# Own data set consisting of numbers (csv) at PyTorch

Tags: neural-network, pytorch, dataset

I want to use my own dataset, which consists of numbers, in PyTorch. They are therefore available as a csv file, for example. What is the easiest way to do load this into PyTorch? So far I only know how to use already existing datasets in PyTorch, but I don't want to do that.

Comment: https://stanford.edu/~shervine/blog/pytorch-how-to-generate-data-parallel this can be a very good starting point for you

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a custom class that inherits from Pytorch's Dataset class.
Then, you need to wrap it with a DataLoader.

Follow this tutorial for an in depth explanation:

https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/basics/data_tutorial.html#creating-a-custom-dataset-for-your-files

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to import your dataset would be to:

1. Use `pandas` package to load your csv file:

```
    import pandas as pd 
    data = pd.read_csv("filename.csv")
```

2. Then, implement a very simple pytorch `Dataset` class as described [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/0.2.0/data.html#torch.utils.data.Dataset).
3. You will finally pass your instance of `Dataset` as the first parameter of a pytorch [DataLoader](https://pytorch.org/docs/0.2.0/data.html#torch.utils.data.DataLoader)